# Indexing mongodb collection with 2dsphere indexes and IP address indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geojson, ip-geolocation

I am new to MongoDB and want to create a Database with location data(lat-long) stored in the collection. I plan to create GeoJSON objects to store this data.
I want to know if I can create 2 indexes on this collection out of which one is the 2Dsphere index and another index can be any other value like IP addresses which are unique in the same collection?
And if this is possible how do I create these indexes?

Comment: I have created a collection and want to index it but not sure how to do it. db.collection.ensureIndex(<field1><field2>....) will allow me to create an index on multiple fields but I don't know how to create an index which has 2dsphere index as well as the ipaddress index.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
db.position.ensureIndex({"geoField.coordinates":"2dsphere","ipaddress":1})
```

Take a look at [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/)

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Antonio 
In this case the document object will be as follows right? Correct me if I am wrong
{geoField: {type:Point
            coordinates:[lat, long]}
ipaddress: 122.0.0.7
connection: wi-fi
}

Comment: Well, if your documents are like this: `{"geoField":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[lat,long]},"ipaddress":"122.0.0.7","connection":"wi-fi"}` ... then your statement to create the index would look like this:  `db.collection.ensureIndex({"geoField.coordinates":"2dsphere"},{"ipaddress":1})`

Comment: Should the ensureIndex format not be : db.position.ensureIndex({"geoField":"2dsphere","ipaddress":1})

Comment: Yes, that's the right syntax for a compound index. Answer edited. Thanks.